# many many dpkg errors while upgrading

Tags: ubuntu, apt, upgrade, dpkg

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, newly upgraded from 12.04. I was trying to upgrade my software, but it is showing many, many dpkg errors regarding `texlive-*`.

When I type following command:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get the following error:

```
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/05TeXMF.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/15Plain.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/45TeXinputs.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/55Fonts.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/65BibTeX.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/75DviPS.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/80DVIPDFMx.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/85Misc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/90TeXDoc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/95NonPath.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... 
updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.kk3Qciew
Please include this file if you report a bug.

Sometimes, not accepting conffile updates in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
causes updmap-sys to fail.  Please check for files with extension
.dpkg-dist or .ucf-dist in this directory

dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-sanskrit:
 latex-sanskrit depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-sanskrit (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-base:
 texlive-latex-base depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
```

and many more of such types.

How can I fix this?
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The output of the command ::  apt-get install tex-common is following ::

find: `/etc/texmf/texmf.d': No such file or directory
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... 
updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.8Lse0Bt5
Please include this file if you report a bug.

Sometimes, not accepting conffile updates in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
causes updmap-sys to fail.  Please check for files with extension
.dpkg-dist or .ucf-dist in this directory

dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-sanskrit:
 latex-sanskrit depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-sanskrit (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-base:
 texlive-latex-base depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-generic-recommended:
 texlive-generic-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-generic-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-pstricks:
 texlive-pstricks depends on texlive-generic-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-generic-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive-pstricks depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-pstricks (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of asymptote:
 asymptote depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 asymptote depends on texlive-pstricks; however:
  Package texlive-pstricks is not configured yet.
 asymptote depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package asymptote (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-recommended:
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cm-super-minimal:
 cm-super-minimal depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 cm-super-minimal depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cm-super-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cm-super:
 cm-super depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 cm-super depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 cm-super depends on cm-super-minimal (= 0.3.4-9); however:
  Package cm-super-minimal is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package cm-super (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-metapost:
 texlive-metapost depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package texlive-metapost (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of context:
 context depends on texlive-metapost (>= 2013); however:
  Package texlive-metapost is not configured yet.
 context depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package context (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of context-modules:
 context-modules depends on context (>> 2011); however:
  Package context is not configured yet.
 context-modules depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package context-modules (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-font-utils:
 texlive-font-utils depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-font-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-extra-utils:
 texlive-extra-utils depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-extra-utils depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package texlive-extra-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of feynmf:
 feynmf depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 feynmf depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 feynmf depends on texlive-font-utils; however:
  Package texlive-font-utils is not configured yet.
 feynmf depends on texlive-extra-utils; however:
  Package texlive-extra-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package feynmf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-xcolor:
 latex-xcolor depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 latex-xcolor depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-xcolor (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-beamer:
 latex-beamer depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on latex-xcolor (>= 2.00-1); however:
  Package latex-xcolor is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-beamer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-common:
 latex-cjk-common depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-common depends on texlive-font-utils (>= 2007.dfsg.2-1); however:
  Package texlive-font-utils is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-common depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-chinese:
 latex-cjk-chinese depends on latex-cjk-common (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-chinese depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-chinese (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-japanese:
 latex-cjk-japanese depends on latex-cjk-common (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-japanese depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-japanese (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-korean:
 latex-cjk-korean depends on latex-cjk-common (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-korean depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-korean (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-other:
 texlive-lang-other depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-other (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-thai:
 latex-cjk-thai depends on latex-cjk-common (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-thai depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-thai depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-thai depends on texlive-lang-other (>= 2013.20130523-1); however:
  Package texlive-lang-other is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-thai (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-cjk-all:
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-common (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-common is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-chinese (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-chinese is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-japanese (>= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-japanese is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-korean (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-korean is not configured yet.
 latex-cjk-all depends on latex-cjk-thai (= 4.8.3+git20120914-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package latex-cjk-thai is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package latex-cjk-all (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latexmk:
 latexmk depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package latexmk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of m-tx:
 m-tx depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package m-tx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of musixtex:
 musixtex depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package musixtex (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pmx:
 pmx depends on tex-common (>= 4); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 pmx depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pmx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of purifyeps:
 purifyeps depends on texlive-metapost; however:
  Package texlive-metapost is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package purifyeps (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended:
 texlive-fonts-recommended depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive:
 texlive depends on texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive depends on texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-fonts-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-bibtex-extra:
 texlive-bibtex-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-bibtex-extra depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-bibtex-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-extra:
 texlive-fonts-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-extra-doc:
 texlive-fonts-extra-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-extra-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended-doc:
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package texlive-fonts-recommended-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-formats-extra:
 texlive-formats-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-formats-extra depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-formats-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-polish:
 texlive-lang-polish depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-lang-polish depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-polish (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-generic-extra:
 texlive-generic-extra depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package texlive-generic-extra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-indic:
 texlive-lang-indic depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-indic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-spanish:
 texlive-lang-spanish depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-spanish (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-omega:
 texlive-omega depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 texlive-omega depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-omega (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-cyrillic:
 texlive-lang-cyrillic depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.
 texlive-lang-cyrillic depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-cyrillic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-humanities-doc:
 texlive-humanities-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package texlive-humanities-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-english:
 texlive-lang-english depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-english (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fragmaster:
 fragmaster depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 fragmaster depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 fragmaster depends on texlive-extra-utils; however:
  Package texlive-extra-utils is not configured yet.
 fragmaster depends on texlive-font-utils; however:
  Package texlive-font-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fragmaster (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-extra-doc:
 texlive-latex-extra-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-latex-extra-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-publishers-doc:
 texlive-publishers-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package texlive-publishers-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-lang-european:
 texlive-lang-european depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package texlive-lang-european (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-pictures-doc:
 texlive-pictures-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package texlive-pictures-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-metapost-doc:
 texlive-metapost-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package texlive-metapost-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-science-doc:
 texlive-science-doc depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
  Package tex-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: error processing package texlive-science-doc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
 latex-sanskrit
 texlive-latex-base
 texlive-generic-recommended
 texlive-pstricks
 asymptote
 texlive-latex-recommended
 cm-super-minimal
 cm-super
 texlive-metapost
 context
 context-modules
 texlive-font-utils
 texlive-extra-utils
 feynmf
 latex-xcolor
 latex-beamer
 latex-cjk-common
 latex-cjk-chinese
 latex-cjk-japanese
 latex-cjk-korean
 texlive-lang-other
 latex-cjk-thai
 latex-cjk-all
 latexmk
 m-tx
 musixtex
 pmx
 purifyeps
 texlive-fonts-recommended
 texlive
 texlive-bibtex-extra
 texlive-fonts-extra
 texlive-fonts-extra-doc
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc
 texlive-formats-extra
 texlive-lang-polish
 texlive-generic-extra
 texlive-lang-indic
 texlive-lang-spanish
 texlive-omega
 texlive-lang-cyrillic
 texlive-humanities-doc
 texlive-lang-english
 fragmaster
 texlive-latex-extra-doc
 texlive-publishers-doc
 texlive-lang-european
 texlive-pictures-doc
 texlive-metapost-doc
 texlive-science-doc
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

and the output of the command apt-cache policy tex-common is as follows ::
tex-common:
  Installed: 4.04
  Candidate: 4.04
  Version table:
 *** 4.04 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

Comment: Your problem appears to be with tex-common. Can you post the output of `apt-get install tex-common`? Also, post the output of `apt-cache policy tex-common`. Both in the question, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be [Ubuntu bug #1236951](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tex-common/+bug/1236951).  See the link for workarounds and the status of a fix.

Comment: No, thats not helping me.

Comment: @mubeena Did you see this in the bug report: "I also had this problem after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04. My TeX install was broken afterwards. I eventually got it working by uninstalling all tex-related packages, deleting /etc/texmf/texmf.d/, and reinstalling the tex packages."

Comment: Yes, I have uninstalled  all tex packages and reinstalled them twice, but thats also not working for me.

Comment: @mubeena: It seems that removing config files is an important step, did you do that?  Otherwise, I'm not sure what to suggest except to wait for a fix (it appears that it is actively being worked on) or start debugging it yourself.

Comment: Actually I think, I was not ablt to remove all packages carefully and thats why my reinstallation didnt work. I followed the following steps, from the thread given here,   sudo apt-get remove --purge tex-common texlive-*
    sudo rm /etc/texmf/
    sudo apt-get install tex-common
    sudo apt-get install texlive-base
    sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended  :: and this worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `apt-get install -f`. If this doesn't fix your system, then something is really wrong, and a fix might be to remove the TeX related packages and try again.

Comment: No, again the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Same situation for me, remove the older directory, then reinstall:

```
sudo apt remove --purge tex-common texlive-*
sudo rm -rf /etc/texmf/
sudo apt install tex-common texlive-base texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended latex-cjk-all
```